# If an infinite sequence has no last element, why do we say the $\sqrt2$ is irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

The arguments I've seen for certain square roots being irrational (like $\sqrt2$) boil down to proving by contradiction that if we assume p/q to be fully reduced we'll find that both p and q must be even (in the case of $\sqrt2$) and :boom: contradiction.

But if I allow p to have an infinite number of digits (a valid member of the integers) then it has no last digit and cannot be classified as even or odd. Right? The proof by infinite descent, for example, seems to assume we can't descend infinitely but why not? I must be missing something important here about the integers.

Similarly, why not define pi as the fraction 314159.../100000...? I believe both are valid integers.

I've often heard people loosely describe rational numbers as the set of numbers whose decimal representations terminate or repeat, but I don't see what limits the construction of an arbitrarily large integer by an infinite process. Lets for example attempt to construct the numerator in the quotient above:

Step 1: Construct the number 3 (1+1+1 = 3)
Step 2: Construct 31 (3+1+1...+1 = 28)
Step 3: Construct 314 (you get the idea)

It seems I could continue the process above indefinitely and produce a valid integer at every step. Because it is an infinite process any one step has a finite integer, but the number this process describes is unlimited.

Is the number this process describes then not an integer?

---

**Update**
As commenters and answerers of this question have pointed out, my question assumes that a number with an infinite number of digits could be called an integer. That underlying assumption has confused some readers of my question so I've edited the above in an attempt to make the meat of my question clearer.

To that end, I'd like to point out that the essence of my question is either very similar to or a duplicate of [A "number" with an infinite number of digits is a natural number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58085/a-number-with-an-infinite-number-of-digits-is-a-natural-number).

Comment: why do you say integers can have infinite digits? What do you mean by such a statement?

Comment: Usually, things like whole numbers/integers must be finite.... this is... by definition.

Comment: Where you go wrong is the statement , "infinite number of digits (a valid member of the integers." Integers, as constructed in something like Peano arithmetic, are defined as iterated finite sums of $\pm 1$.

Comment: To downvoters; why? This is a perfectly normal question by someone who's obviously thought about the problem and this question is certainly *not* unclear or not useful. The fact that his or her vision on the natural numbers isn't as it should be does not make the question bad.

Comment: @vrugtehagel: the last paragraph of the question is hopelessly confused twaddle. If you object to the question being downvoted as unclear, I think you should provide the OP with a clarification of all the confusions in the question.

Comment: "hopelessly confused twaddle" well he's confused for sure that's why he's asking a question here but it's not hopeless and not twaddle either. Furthermore, me remarking that the question isn't bad does not in any way require me to answer it (nor does it mean I have the ability to explain the OP's problems properly).

Comment: @vrugtehagel  I'd take your argument a bit more seriously if the asker made an effort to reply to at least one of the first three comments, as best as s/he can. It's been an hour now.  No edits from the asker to address the comments, no comment to reply to comments.  A simple reply or edit, from the asker goes a long way.

Comment: Wow, things move fast on Math StackExchange! Within 5 minutes of posting, I had the first 3 comments just mentioned and a 4th asking about downvoters. Within 10, I'd been both defended and maligned by a small community. I didn't realize I was supposed to be available for live feedback after posting. Lesson learned! It seems the community's consensus is unanimous on the answer to my question. Both of the answers given so far have been equally helpful, I suppose I'll mark one as "accepted", but I'll give it a day here to see if anyone else hops on and wants to pitch in. Thanks all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither $314159\ldots$ nor $100000\ldots$ are valid integers. Integers are characterized by being *finite* sequences of digits. Integers cannot be infinite; that's exactly what we mean by the word "integer".

The integers are *counting numbers* (and their negatives); that is to say, they are numbers one might use to count. You can't count to $100000\ldots$ - for one thing, there's no "previous" number to count from. The key idea is that the integers are the numbers we can "see"; I can show you $43$ sheep, and in principle I could show you $43000000000$ sheep, but I can't show you a convincing $\pi$ sheep. Rational numbers are numbers we can build using comparisons between the numbers we can "see"; Jack can have $1.5$ times as many sheep as Jill, but he can't have $\sqrt{2}$ times as many sheep as Jennifer, no matter what number of sheep Jennifer has. Allowing integers to have infinitely many digits would defeat this "concrete" idea of what an integer is, so we define integers to be only finite.

Comment: If I understand your point, it is somewhat philosophical. We *could* define the integers to include numbers like the one I described (in my reworded question), but that would go against the *intent* of the integers. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @KCE Yes, we could - just like we *could* define integers to include $\sqrt[3]{7}$ or apples; but if we did, it wouldn't be what we actually mean by "integer".

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing as an integer with infinitely many digits.

With a bit of ingenuity it is possible to define arithmetic on infinite strings of digits (it's easier if they are infinite *towards the left*, leading to "10-adic integers", which despite the confusing name are not really integers) -- but the result of this will not be what we call integers.

One definition of what a (positive) integer is, is:

> - $1$ is a positive integer.
> - If $a$ is a positive integer, then $a+1$ is also a positive integer.
> - Nothing else is a positive integer.

Now consider the set of numbers that *can* be written down such they have a first and last digit. This certainly includes $1$, and adding $1$ to something in this set will again lead to a member of the set.

According to the definition above, this means that *everything outside that set* falls under the "nothing else is a positive integer" clause -- or in other words, every positive integer has the property that it has a first and last digit (when written down in base ten).

---

In your edited question you describe a *sequence* of integers, but having a sequence of ever-larger integers is by far not the same as having constructed one integer with infinitely many digits. Mathematics is in general wary of notions of "completed infinite process" -- they are very useful as a visualization technique, so you will often see that kind of description in informal discussions, but they can also lead to false results, so they are not accepted as arguments for truth unless it is clear how they can be reduced to precise *definitions* without any infinitary handwaving.

In calculus and analysis, this reduction-to-definition usually goes via the concept of *limits*, but that doesn't work in your case because *not every sequence has a limit*, and yours in particular doesn't. So, since the usual assumption doesn't work here, the onus would now be on you to explain how your infinite-process imagery reduces to concrete timeless facts. And you can't do that without *somehow* leaving the realm of what we call integers.

(The closest thing I can think of here would be the somewhat esoteric area of "non-standard analysis via ultraproducts", in which your process does make some sense and produces a "non-standard rational number whose difference from $\pi$ is infinitesimal but nonzero". Of course, the non-standard rationals of non-standard analysis are not what we usually call rationals either).

Intuitively though, you can think about this: You seem to say that your infinite process does not preserve the property of "having a first and a last digit" -- each element in your sequence has this property, but the thing you claim results at the end doesn't. On the other hand, you're tacitly assuming that your process does preserve the property of "being an integer" -- why is that? Once we accept that the process does not preserve all properties, there has to be something in particular about "being an integer" that makes it be preserved, before we can just assume it is.

Comment: I've updated my question a little (to get this question reopened) in the direction of your answer. I added a "construction" of an integer with infinite digits, and it seems that all of the intermediate steps produce integers with first and last digits as you pointed out. Can you please update your answer to address the reworded question "Is the number this process describes then not an integer?"

Comment: @KCE: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept further, it helps me see better the subtle edge that gets crossed with the kind of reasoning I've used in my question.

Answer (score 1):

> But if I allow $p$ to have an infinite number of digits (a valid member
>   of the integers) then it has no last digit and cannot be classified as
>   even or odd. Right?

One has to be careful about numbers and their representation as a sequence of symbols.

Let me try to point out some issues with extension to representations with infinite many digits:

For our usual decimal representation of a non-negative integer with $m\in \mathbb{N}$ digits from $D = \{ 0, \dotsc, 9 \}$ and semantic
$$
(\cdot)_{10} : D^m \to \mathbb{N} \\
(d_{m-1} \dotsb d_0)_{10} = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} d_k 10^k
$$

we need a last digit $d_0$.

In fact the meaning of the first digit $d_{m-1}$ of that word, as a multiple of $10^{m-1}$, we only know because we start assigning the powers of $10$ from the right end of the sequence of digit symbols.

An infinite sequence of digits ($\omega$-word) given as
$$
3\dotsb
$$
which we interpret as an infinite sequence of digits starting with a $3$ digit symbol, is not useful, as it gives us no clue what $3$-multiple of some power of the base $10$ it is: Three tens? Hundreds? Bazillions?

If we would grow the digit sequence to the other side
$$
\dotsb 3
$$
or use a less ambigious notation to specify the $\omega$-word, e.g. as word of the accepted language of a Büchi automaton, the situation, is not much better: If the sequence honours the convention of not using leading $0$ digits there must show up non-zero digits repeatedly (otherwise we had a finite sequence) and the extended semantic 
$$
(.)_{10} : D^\omega \to \mathbb{N} \\
((d_k))_{10} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} d_k 10^k
$$
would be infinite. Alas all integer numbers are of finite value, and there is no largest integer. So this is not a useful representation for an integer number.

Comment: I feel like your answer is somewhat related to @reese's answer. It supposes that I want to represent an integer with a finite number of digits or in a way that leaves notation like 3... and ...3 unambiguous. As you say, it's not "useful" to represent an integer this way due to the nature of what we want an integer to be. Would you agree or am I off the mark?

Comment: No, I had the impression you wanted to use some infinite length word of digits.